# getting info from table 2 with the info from table 1

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

I'm not experienced with SQL (and also not THAT much with php)

I'm currently am getting my info from a table from my database and putting it on my Website.  Now I'm trying to get info from another table trough data from my 1st table through `$sql = "SELECT * FROM patients";`

Example: In my current syntax row 3 called "species_id" is a '1'. In another table the ID is 1 and species = "cat". I want cat in my row where I drop the info from the first table.

in theory I want something like:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM patients SELECT species_description 
        FROM species 
        WHERE species_id=species_id;";
```

(which obviously doesn't work but I wanted you to have a better idea)
How do I correctly do this (the best way)?

Comment: can you share your SQL table structure ? you can probably acheive the result you want with just one SQL request using a JOIN statement.

Comment: sorry i am a total noob at sql and database.. do you mean just my table?

Comment: You have to use SQL Joins in your query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming you have species_id in your patientes table and this is the relation value for the id in species you could 
buil a join

```
    $sql = "SELECT patients.* , species.species_description
            FROM patients
            INNER JOIN species on patients.species_id=species.id;";
```

Comment: thank you! this sort of fixed it! please look at the answer i posted

Comment: @SvenElmendorp  .. wrong where removed .. many thanks  ..  upvoted

Answer (score 1):

thanks everyone for an answer, i fixed it using this code

```
$sql = "SELECT patients.* , species.species_description
    FROM patients
    INNER JOIN species on patients.species_id = species.species_id;";
```

thanks to the answer from [@scaisEdge](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3522312/scaisedge) (thank you!) and w3schools page on how to use INNER JOIN (never knew about that before) thanks!

Comment: You should not copy the answer. Only accept and upvote the answer which helps you

Comment: i didnt, i took the closest answer and changed it a lil